# Grid set field property

Tags: extjs, grid, set, field

I have a grid with one column like this:

```
{
    text: 'Mercado',
    type: 'int',
    flex: 1,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'idMercadoProd',
    field: {xtype:"combo", store:storeMercadosCombo, displayField:"mercado", valueField:"id"},
    renderer: function(value) {
        value = parseInt(value);
        var texto = gridMercado.getStore().findRecord("id", value).get("mercado");
        return Ext.String.format(texto);
    }
}
```

I want to change the field property, to set to null under certain circumstances.
I have searched and I can't find a set command for that.
What is the command that makes me change the field property?